# How to call property of calling class

Tags: python

For context I'm very new to classes and Python in general.

I have Class `Bot` and Class `BotSub`

In `Bot` I have something `self.driver`, and later I call `BotSub()`. From `BotSub`, how can I call `Bot`'s `self.driver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the `Bot` object (which is on `self` argument) to the `BotSub` class, and it has to use that to call back methods on the `Bot` object.

For example:

```
class Bot(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.botsub = BotSub(self)

   def driver(self):
       ...

   def update(self):
       self.botsub.dothings()

class BotSub(object):
   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.bot = bot

   def dothing(self):
       self.bot.driver()
```

Alternatively, you don't need to keep the parent Bot instance as an attribute on the BotSub - just pass it as a parameter whenever you call methods on it that will need a reference to the bot:

```
...
class Bot(object):
   ...
   def update(self):
       self.botsub.dothings(self)

class BotSub(object):
   ...
   def dothings(self, bot):
        bot.driver()
        ...
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. When updating `self` on `Bot`, will it automatically update on `BotSub` even after the first `init`ialization?

Comment: Yes, what the BotSub will have is  a reference to the live Bot object - any changes in it will be visible imediatelly on the botsub code (because it will be looking at the exact same object)